# Помогите с уствовкой redis на ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, redis

Здраствуйте,недавно перешел на ubuntu. Пришло время установить редис. Во время sudo systemctl status redis -->
[image: ошибка в activated]

почитал в инете нужно было поменять supervised , поменял и ничего не помогло, помогите пожалуста
[image: supervised - sysemd]

Comment: Читайте логи службы целиком, а не только последние пять строчек

Comment: А как ты редиску ставил-то?